# Print Stream Information

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, tcplistener

im trying to print the information  sent  to port 2000   but all I get is “ System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream” . is there a way to convert stream to a string?   Or a way  to just print the stream information directly .

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpListener TL = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2000);
            TL.Start();
            Socket S = TL.AcceptSocket();
            Stream SS = new NetworkStream(S);
            string MSG = SS.ToString(); 
            Console.WriteLine(MSG);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: here is the client

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {

            try
            {
                TcpClient TC = new TcpClient();
                TC.Connect("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 2000);
                NetworkStream Writer = TC.GetStream();
                string MSG = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] pack = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MSG);
                Writer.Write(pack, 0, pack.Length);
                Writer.Flush();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" faild");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }


    }
```

PS: also the application crashes  after execution

Comment: Use try/catch block to avoid application crash. And @L.B. gave you an asnwer, do not call streams' object ToString to obtain stream data, use StreamReader instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code:

```
SS.ToString();
```

will always return `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream`! because `ToString()` function returns a string represents the current object, you can use a `StreamReader` to read a line from a stream.

```
Stream SS = new NetworkStream(S);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(SS);
string MSG = reader.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(MSG);
```

of course you should run the server program before the client, because TCP is connection oriented.

Answer (score 0):

If the other part is sending a string (not binary data that can  not be converted to string) then you can try

```
var s = new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(S));
s.Readline();
s.ReadToEnd(); //OR
```

Comment: i've updated  the code but it still doesn't   write the text.

It clearly gets the information it just wont  print it

Comment: How do you know  `It clearly gets the information`?  Which code do you use Readline or ReadtoEnd? if you don't send `Environment.NewLine` ReadLine will never return. ReadToEnd only returns when the other side closes the connection.

Comment: the moment I send the information from the client  to the reader   the  application crashes . It does that  whenever after a connection is closed  ( its a windows xp problem that im to lazy to fix ) . also  I use ReadtoEnd(); and the connection is  closed right after the info has been sent .

PS: it  crashes after the text  is supposed to be shown . So Its not what stops it from printing